# Perl package Manager is not opening

Tags: perl

I am using the ActivePerl-5.20.2.2002-MSWin32-x86-64int-299195 version.
After installation of above version sw I am unable to open the Perl Package Manager. which much needfulll.

further ActivePerl-5.22.1.2201-MSWin32-x64-299574
but after installation same result.

I try to debug this..
i got few few old reference but which not that much helped me to solve this problem.

I am using windows 7 64 bit system

Also set env as HTTP_proxy to "http://proxy:8080"
and 
HTTP_proxy_user ; HTTP_proxy_pass as mine admin username & password.
refernce link :http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.6/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_and_proxies

but still situation remain as it is.

Comment: What does "unable to open the Perl Package Manager" mean?  What *does* happen?  What do you try and what do you see?

Comment: hi testing purpose i use the perl script in that i use the package modules..with PPM GUI it is very to install Lib..currently i ma doing it manually...when we install active perl set it automatically with setup it will install the PPM ..i can see perl package manager in all programs but wheb i click on it wPPM GUI windoiws it self is not coming...

Comment: Hello if someone knows how to install Perl module by using cpan plz share the procedure.. I tried  but showings nmake. Error...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I solved it, I cleanned AppData folder of ActivePerl.

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\ActiveState\ActivePerl\

Delete all data from that folder. Rerun `ppm` everything works fine now!